# What is the javascript regex to return only the numeric portion of an SSN

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var ssn = "123-45-6789";
```

What is the javascript regex to return only the numeric portion of SSN?
I need to test that they entered exactly 9 digits.

I don't know why I just have to re-learn regex the few times a year I need it. I've got a block for regex.

Thanks ever so much.

Comment: There are several duplicates in the "related" column that might help

Comment: Why not just replace the dashes with the empty string: ssn.replace("-", "")? Also getting to remember regexes is a fairly good investment ;)

Comment: For some reason, the thought of touching a SSN with JavaScript inspires a deep sense of fear and trepidation in me... Like this should only be the business of back-end application code.

Comment: ... unless of course, this is back-end code with Node.js or some such thing.

Comment: It's legit on the frontend as well - validate that it's exactly 9 digits  so you can give the user immediate feedback, then do final verification on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var digits = ssn.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Simply removes all non-digit characters.

Comment: @David If it works for you, it would be polite to check jvenema's answer as the accepted one.